# Node.js req.app.locals data sends every time when switching pages and return back

Tags: node.js, express, message

I have got an app thats sending post request to some URL. Looks like this:

```
module.exports.newevent_post = async (req,res, err) => {
    try {
      // necessary code

          await Event.create({
            // necessary code
        })
      
          req.app.locals.success = 'Your event is successfully created';
          res.redirect("/events");
    } catch (error) {
      res.redirect("/events/newevent")
    }
}
```

and i got the req.app.locals object in the GET method:

```
module.exports.home_get = async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const successMessage = req.app.locals.success; 
        res.locals.successMessage = successMessage

        res.render("events.ejs")
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error)
    }
}
```

The problem is, whenever i post the request and the req.app.locals has been send and i got the message, for example before refreshing that page, i clicked to some link and go another page and then i return back, the message is has send again and it happens everytime unless i refresh the page. How do i make it send one time even when i navigate through pages?